# Accuracy is always 0 in SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER (Android)

Tags: android, accelerometer

I'm programming a application that needs to get data from the accelerometer sensor.

I have overwritten both onAccuracyChanged() and onSensorChanged() functions. It is suppoused that those functions are only called when accuracy or values of the sensor changes, but in my case they change many times per second, and always returning the same values.

```
    @Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    if(sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
        Log.d(TAG, "Accuracy has changed: "+accuracy);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
        x = event.values[SensorManager.DATA_X];
        y = event.values[SensorManager.DATA_Y];
        z = event.values[SensorManager.DATA_Z];
        Log.d(TAG, "Sensor changed: "+ event.accuracy+", "+x+", "+y+", "+z);
    }       
}
```

This is annoying, but it is also annoying that the accuracy is always 0 (SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE), so I can't trust it.

What can be happening? The device is a Samsung Galaxy S, so it has accelerometer.

Thanks!

Comment: accuracy depends upon the hardware configuration of sensor.You cannot fix it by your code.

Comment: Good question. I find the same in sony ericson xperia x10 mini pro and on htc desire.  Moreover, I think I see different precision each time I run and change setting in my apps..

Answer (score 0):

u can the value returned is in float value and very accurate
u can just convert them to integer or even use condition to get result only when the phone in specific position

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){

        x = event.values[SensorManager.DATA_X];

        y = event.values[SensorManager.DATA_Y];

        z = event.values[SensorManager.DATA_Z];

        if( x > -3 && x < 3  && y > -3 && y < 3  && z < -7 && z > -13  ){
         // this will return value only when the phone is upside down on the table
         // u can set as ur own liking
         Log.d(TAG, "Sensor changed: "+ event.accuracy+", "+x+", "+y+", "+z);
        }
    }       
}
```